# android working in background proximity alarm

Tags: android, multithreading, background, alarm, onpause

im learning to use android development and to try it i want to make a "proximity alarm".
When im near to some point i need to ring the alarm.

Firstly i made a loop to calculate the distance between the point and our position, and when it's less than one distance, ring the alarm.

its ok, but... logically when you put the alarm you can play other applications, so whats happend with mine??

i need to use onPaused() method? maybe create a thread?? im lost in this moment, someone know how to do? o give me some advice?

THANKSSS =)

this is my code... now using asyncTask, obviusly doesnt work, some helP?

public class RunActivity extends MapActivity {

```
private MapView map;
private MapController mapControl;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_run);

    this.map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
    this.map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);       

    this.mapControl = map.getController();

    GeoPoint centro = new GeoPoint((int)(40.463667 * 1E6), (int)(-3.749220 * 1E6));
    this.mapControl.setCenter(centro);
    this.mapControl.setZoom(10);

    List<Overlay> capas = this.map.getOverlays();
    MyLocationOverlay mOverlayLocation = new MyLocationOverlay(this, this.map);

    mOverlayLocation.enableMyLocation();
    mOverlayLocation.enableCompass();

    capas.add(mOverlayLocation);

    this.map.postInvalidate();

    MiTareaAsincrona Ejemplo = new MiTareaAsincrona();
    Ejemplo.execute(RunActivity.this);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}


class MiTareaAsincrona extends AsyncTask<Context, Double, Boolean> {

    private boolean finish = false;
    private double target_lat;
    private double target_lon;

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        Bundle Datos = getIntent().getBundleExtra("Datos");
        this.target_lat = Datos.getInt("LATITUD");
        this.target_lon = Datos.getInt("LONGITUD");

    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... context) {      

        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)context[0].getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {

            double actual_lat;
            double actual_lon;
            Bundle Datos = getIntent().getBundleExtra("Datos");

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                actual_lat = location.getLatitude()*1E6;
                actual_lon = location.getLongitude()*1E6;

                if (distance(actual_lat, actual_lon, target_lat, target_lon) < Datos.getInt("DISTANCIA")) {
                    finish = true;
                }

            }
        };

        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
        return finish;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate() { }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (finish) {
            Log.v("OJU", "MIARMA");
        }
    }

    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
    /*::  This function converts decimal degrees to radians             :*/
    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
    private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
      double theta = lon1 - lon2;
      double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
      dist = Math.acos(dist);
      dist = rad2deg(dist);
      dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344 * 1000; // en metros

      return (dist);
    }

    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
    /*::  This function converts decimal degrees to radians             :*/
    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
    private double deg2rad(double deg) {
      return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }

    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
    /*::  This function converts radians to decimal degrees             :*/
    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
    private double rad2deg(double rad) {
      return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
    }       

}
```

}

Comment: It's hard to tell what you need to do without seeing what you have done. The general pattern to this, however, is that you have a Service running in the background to track location updates, and when your proximity alarm hits, you set a Notification which can include an alarm sound.

Comment: i didnt start, i only show one map (in oncreate()) with the target point and actual position.
i have the function to calculate the distance between them and no more, only i want to know when i must to make the loop to calculate the distance when the gps give a new position =)

sorry if i dont write correctly